# Stack Exchange Android app doesn't allow login with Facebook account

Tags: bug, android-app, login, facebook

When logging in with a Facebook account, I'm receiving this error:

> Unable to verify your Facebook account.

Do you know if this is a known issue?

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Try using the Facebook app that is installed on your device first, make sure you're logged in there.

Comment: I did that.. but still didn't work.

Comment: As a workaround I added my Google account to my stack overflow account. And that worked

Comment: Weird... glad you found a workaround, maybe add this as answer? :)

Comment: This still needs to be fixed anyway

Comment: I had the same problem with `Pinterest` web... Maybe it's an issue with Facebook login mask?